# How to condese this jQuery function

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

This is part of a function of a progress bar [jquery-asProgress.js] trying to work out how to condense this jquery function either through simplified structure or if it's possible to have this query find value <100 and >69 (not sure if this is possible).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.progress[data-goal="99"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="98"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="97"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="96"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="95"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="94"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="93"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="92"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="91"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="90"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="89"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="88"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="87"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="86"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="85"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="84"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="83"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="82"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="81"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="80"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="79"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="78"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="77"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="76"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="75"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="74"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="73"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="72"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="71"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
    $('.progress[data-goal="70"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
});
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a selector string by iterating over numbers from 70 to 99:

```
let selector = '.progress[data-goal="70"]';
for (let i = 71; i <= 99; i++) {
  selector += `, .progress[data-goal="${i}"]`;
}
$(selector).find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
```

If the elements being selected here are the *only* ones with a `data-goal` that starts with 7, 8, or 9, you can also use `^=` ("attribute starts with") syntax:

```
$('.progress[data-goal^="7"], .progress[data-goal^="8"], .progress[data-goal^="9"]').find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
```

(if you have elements like `data-goal="3"` in the ones place, you might consider changing them to `data-goal="03"` so they have a leading zero)

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance, both of the solutions appear to work, however the first one (selector string) appears to be giving me syntax errors, despite it working, could you take a look and let me know where I've gone wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(function($) {
  let selector = '.progress[data-goal="70"]';
  for (let i = 71; i <= 99; i++) {
    selector += `, .progress[data-goal="${i}"]`;
  }
  $(selector).find('.progress__bar').addClass('wishlist_cash_add');
 });   
</script>
```

Comment: There are no syntax errors in that code. If your IDE doesn't understand template literals, you should strongly consider upgrading it to something modern - ES2015 was 5 years ago

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Currently stuck using Dreamweaver as our back end is running ASP classic and more modern IDEs are not accepted by our backend devs. Do you have a suggestion that might support both? I currently bulk transfer code between Dreamweaver, Notepad :) and Brackets to troubleshoot various elements.